# PHP regex to match HTML tag names except some tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to match any open HTML tag except `input` tag using regular expression in PHP. Here is my pattern.

```
/<([a-z]+)([^>]*>)?/i
```

It matches all below:

```
<input type="text">
<img src=">
<a href="">
<button type="button"></button>
<div id="some"></div>
<p></p>
```

I don't want to match `input`. I may exclude more tags in the future as I stated **some tags** in my question title.

### [What I've tried so far](https://regex101.com/r/lP7uV7/2)

#### [Edit]

As per my example, I also want to keep the tag name only returned in the matched results, e.g, `img`, `a`, `button`, `div`, `p`, etc.

Comment: Add a [negative assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<(?:(?!input)[^>])*>(?:<\/[^>]*>)?
```

Try this.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/13

```
$re = "/<(?:(?!input)[^>])*>(?:<\\/[^>]*>)?/im";
$str = "<input type=\"text\">\n<img src=\">\n<a href=\"\">\n<button type=\"button\"></button>\n<div id=\"some\"></div>\n<p></p>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Edit:

Use

```
(?!<input)<([A-Z0-9a-z]+)([^>]*>)?
```

If you want to save tag separately.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/16

Answer (score 2):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like `(?!input\b)`:

```
<(?!input\b)([\w]+)([^>]*>)?
```

To exclude multiple tags, use `(?!(?:tag1|tag2|tag3|...)\b)`

Comment: Now OP says he does not want `inputasd`.newaz urs is correct as per OP's original question